# Same session variable retrieved in different blocks not stable

Tags: 8, blocks, sessions

I have a module that have three blocks.

```
Block No 1 sets the session
Block No 2 gets the session
Block No 3 remove the session
```

Each block is assigned to a different page.

Now, for some reason this is not working well. I spent the last hours understanding where my mistakes are. The problems are:

1. I don't always see the session value on block 2
2. I don't see the markup in block No 3.
3. The session is not removed in block No 3.
4. The block doesn't always get set in block No 1

This is the block code:

Block 1:

```
namespace Drupal\achva_sso\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Class SsoSessionBlock
 * @package Drupal\achva_sso\Plugin\Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *     id = "achva_sso_session_block",
 *     admin_label = @Translation("Example achva sso session block block")
 * )
 */
class SsoSessionBlock extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(){
        $value = time();
        $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
        $session->set('name', $value);


        return [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $this->t('The output of super SsoSessionBlock block.'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Block 2:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: david_s
 * Date: 14-Nov-18
 * Time: 2:07 PM
 */

namespace Drupal\achva_sso\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Class SsoSessionBlock
 * @package Drupal\module_hero\Plugin\Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *     id = "achva_see_sso_session_block",
 *     admin_label = @Translation("Example achva see sso session block block")
 * )
 */
class SsoSeeSessionBlock extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(){
//        $session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('achva_sso');

        $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
        $details = $session->get('name');

        return [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $details,
        ];

//        $request = \Drupal::request();
//        $session = $request->getSession('name');

//        return [
//            '#type' => 'markup',
//            '#markup' => $session,
//        ];
    }
}
```

Block 3:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\achva_sso\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Class SsoSessionBlock
 * @package Drupal\achva_sso\Plugin\Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *     id = "achva_delete_sso_session_block",
 *     admin_label = @Translation("Example achva delete sso session block block")
 * )
 */
class SsoSessionDestroyBlock extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(){

        $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
        $details = $session->remove('name');
        if($details !== null){
            $a = 'logged in';
        }else{
            $a = 'logged out';
        }



        return [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<p id="aa">sss'. $a .'</p> ',
        ];
    }
}
```

I am totally lost. Any help would be great. Tried to use simple sessions doesn't work well either...

Comment: Are you on your dev site with caching disabled? As in your code it doesn't look like you're doing anything for caching so if you do have caching enabled you'll probably run into issues with that

Comment: No, I don't have cache disabled but I clear the cache after every action I do and than check in chrome incognito mode...

Comment: You need to add cache context to the render array ('session' specifically), and possibly override `getCacheContexts` of the plugin to do the same

Comment: One big question is: How do you render these blocks? Via Twig? Via placement on Block structure page?

Comment: @leymannx Shouldn't make a difference really, cacheability bubbles up

Comment: I use the block layout to connect a node to a block.
How should I render the block?

Comment: I asked this just for clarification. I remembered a question where we had multiple Views rendered via one Twig template and then the caching needed to get busted in between. But your issue is different. Just follow @Clive's suggestion. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199527/15055

Comment: Add the cache context `session` to the block which displays the session details `$build['#cache']['contexts'] = ['session'];`. It's hard to give an advice for the other two blocks, because it doesn't make much sense to set or remove session values in a block.

Comment: @4k4 You're the cache king around here - does the cacheability from the render array bubble up to the plugin itself? As in excluding the need to override `getCacheContexts()`

Comment: @4k4 How do you suggest to do the set and remove? using a service?

Comment: @Clive, yes, the cache metadata from the plugin and the bubbled up metadata from the rendered content is merged. So you don't need to use getCacheContext(). And most times you shouldn't, because if the render array is re-used later for a different purpose, which happens quite often, cache metadata placed elsewhere can easily be overlooked. So my advice would be to always try to put render data and the attached metadata in the same place. This is the concept of bubbleable metadata, to be able to do this.

Comment: @DavSev, the most obvious place would be a controller, called when a user clicks on a link to set or remove the session value.

Comment: I can open a new question but is it possible to load a controller function in all the site pages? I  mean, How do I do it using routing...

Comment: We don't know the business logic of your application. Displaying the session value on all pages makes sense, but why you want to set and remove the session value on all pages?

Comment: First, Thank you for your patiance helping a newbie... I want every page to set the session if it is not already set. I want to have one page that will unset the session. I know how to set the controller function to a spessific path. What I dont know is how to assign a controller function to be loaded in all pages accross the site

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261911/drupal-8-reset-session-each-request